# Differentiate automatic scroll after refresh from other kinds of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have observed that after a refresh, by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or even some `location.reload();`, the browser forces a scroll to the last position it was before the refresh.

The thing is, we track the user's progress across the page, and this "automatic" scroll fires all the checkpoints we have placed all the way to this last position before the refresh.

We are wondering whether is it possible to differ this "automatic" scroll from a scroll made by the user.

For instance, we have lots of:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowMax = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).innerHeight()/2;
  if (windowMax > .....)
});
```

Is there a way to differentiate this two sorts of scrolls?

**Edit**

Please, see that I don't want to prevent the automatic scroll, I want to differ it.

Answer (score 1):

This is something embedded in the users browsers. One way to counter it I suppose is to not have scrolling enabled on body or HTML, and have a custom scroll inside an element that is not on the top layer

You could also deffer recording of the scrolling until the page has fulling been rendered and the document completely loaded.

You could use the following to do stuff when the document is ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: I liked your idea of recording the last position before the refresh. It seems to solve the problem, but requires some cookies and stuff like that. I was seeking for something more fundamental, some browser's api or things like that.

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not suggest this. And I am afraid, as of yet, I don't think there is something of the sort

Comment: My bad, didn't get what you said, I am sorry. So what are you proposing, is there a way of knowing that the page is fully loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a ready event listener and immediately check the `.scrollTop()` after it has been loaded.

```
var isScrolledAfterRefresh;

$(function() {
    isScrolledAfterRefresh = $(window).scrollTop() > 0;
});
```

You do need to be sure that the rest of your code is executed after the ready event is fired.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.